# Why MS Exchange Security Updates come in pair?

Tags: windows, exchange, patch-management, windows-patching

I need to install this security update: https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2022-24463 on Windows Server 2016.

Why there are two items for Windows Server 2016? Should I install only `Update 22` because it includes `Update 21`?

If I need to install both, should I install first `Update 21` then `Update 22`? More in general why do these patches come in pair?

```
Release Date    Product Impact  Severity    Article Download    Details

Mar 8, 2022     Microsoft Exchange Server 2019 Cumulative Update 11 Spoofing    Important   5012698 Security Update CVE-2022-24463
Mar 8, 2022     Microsoft Exchange Server 2016 Cumulative Update 22 Spoofing    Important   5012698 Security Update CVE-2022-24463
Mar 8, 2022     Microsoft Exchange Server 2019 Cumulative Update 10 Spoofing    Important   5012698 Security Update CVE-2022-24463
Mar 8, 2022     Microsoft Exchange Server 2016 Cumulative Update 21 Spoofing    Important   5012698 Security Update CVE-2022-24463
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding Exchange, Microsoft supports the two latests CUs. At this time, the latest Exchange 2019 CU is CU11, therefore, Microsoft provides Security Updates for CU11 and CU10.

So:
If you are running Exchange 2019 **CU11**, then install [**Security Update For** Exchange Server 2019 **CU11** (KB5012698)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=103998)

If you are running Exchange 2019 **CU10**, then install [**Security Update For** Exchange Server 2019 **CU10** (KB5012698)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=103997)

Learn more about Exchange Server Updates here: [Why Exchange Server updates matter - Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/why-exchange-server-updates-matter/ba-p/2280770)

[Overview of CU and SU for Exchange 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/new-features/build-numbers-and-release-dates?view=exchserver-2019#exchange-server-2019)

Comment: How do I check what CU I am currently running?

Comment: @abenci there is a procedure here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/new-features/build-numbers-and-release-dates?view=exchserver-2016